# React-native-google-signin - Cannot read property 'number' of undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-signin

When I implement 
`import { GoogleSignin } from 'react-native-google-signin';`

I get this error: `Cannot read property 'number' of undefined`

I have removed **node_modules** and installed again all dependencies but again I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Check react native version, as in [doc](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin):

> If you use React Native < v0.40 stick with v0.8.1 (npm install react-native-google-signin@0.8 --save).
>
> If you use React Native < v0.47 stick with v0.10.0 (npm install react-native-google-signin@0.10 --save).

Follow the installation guides: [Android](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin/blob/master/docs/android-guide.md) and [iOS](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin/blob/master/docs/ios-guide.md)

Check [this](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin/issues/323) issue as well

Answer (score 0):

React has been updated and doesn't include `propTypes`. Replace the import statement in `GoogleSignIn.ios.js` with below imports:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

Comment: This did not work for for me. I now get 'Cannot read property 'BUTTON_SIZE_ICON' of undefined.... Not to mention, not a huge fan of modifying files in node_modules